# Maximizing the volume of a cylinder with given area

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Consider a right circular cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$. It has volume $V=\pi r^2 h$ and area $A=2\pi r (r+h)$. We are to use Lagrange multipliers to prove the maximum volume with given area is $$ V= \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{A^3}{6\pi}}$$

Here is my attempt. We set up: $$ \mathcal{L} = \pi r^2h - \lambda(2 \pi r^2+2\pi rh)$$ Follows: $$ \mathcal{L}_h = \pi r^2 - \lambda(2\pi r) = 0 $$ $$ \mathcal{L}_r = 2\pi rh - \lambda(4 \pi r+2\pi h) = 0 $$ Set these two equal to each other and noting that $$\mathcal{L}_\lambda = 2\pi r^2 + 2\pi r h = 0 $$ We get $$\boxed{2h=r}$$

Forgive me if I have done something obviously incorrect, but we square the resulting $V$ and cube the resulting $A$ in order to eliminate $r$. Setting $x$ as an arbitrary coefficient. $$V^2 = xA^3$$ $$ \frac{\pi^2 r^6}{4} = x27\pi^3r^6 \implies x = \frac{1}{108\pi} $$ and so $$V= \sqrt{\frac{A^3}{108\pi}} = \frac{1}{6}\sqrt{\frac{A^3}{3\pi}}$$ Painfully close, but not quite the answer required. Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the step before $2h=r$, i get $h=2r$ with the same $\mathcal{L}_h$ and $\mathcal{L}_r$

Comment: Interestingly, this gives the required result, but I cannot see for the life of me where I have gone wrong. Equating $\mathcal{L}_h$ and $\mathcal{L}_r$ as obtained above we get $ 2\pi rh -\lambda(4\pi r +2\pi h)= \pi r^2 - \lambda(2\pi r)$ and so $2\pi rh - \lambda(2\pi r + 2\pi h) = \pi r^2$ where the bracketed term is zero by $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$. Also, why the down votes?

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_h=0 \implies \lambda=\frac{r}{2}$ Then substitute $\lambda$ in $\mathcal{L}_r=0$. Exactly, why the downvotes?

Comment: Yep, I see that now. But can you see what is wrong with my technique of equating $\mathcal{L}_h$ and $\mathcal{L}_r$ ?

Comment: Yes, you have two equations $\mathcal{L}_h=0$ and $\mathcal{L}_r=0$ with three variables and you are looking to get a relationship between two of them (r and h). Saying 0=0 doesn't help to get rid of the $\lambda$. Your $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$ should also be $\mathcal{L}_\lambda=2\pi r (r+h)-A$ with A beeing a constant, the given area, instead of $\mathcal{L}_\lambda=2\pi r (r+h)$

Comment: I see. But surely if we set $\mathcal{L}_h$ equal to $\mathcal{L}_r$ and reduce it down to $$ 2\pi rh -\lambda(2\pi r + 2\pi h) = \pi r^2 $$ We know $ (2\pi r + 2\pi h) = 0$ from the fact that $$ \mathcal{L}_\lambda = 2\pi r^2 + 2\pi r h = 0$$ Which altogether implies $$2\pi rh = \pi r^2 $$ And so $$ 2h = r$$

Comment: That's the point I had missed in the first answer, your definition of $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$ was wrong. You have to define a $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$ which equals zero. In this case we know a formula for the Area, but the Area itself is not 0. You have to substract a constant as pointed in my previous comment.

Comment: Ah yes of course! That makes sense, many thanks for your time kind sir! Much appreciated